# Encoding Special characters in Android Json object

Tags: android, encoding

I am sending json object to server, My url having json object.Json object having special characters,how to encoding special characters in android, please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use [UrlEncode.encode(yourstring, "UTF-8")](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html);

Comment: In JSON URL i am sending °,Empty space (" "), i am using replace method but is there any method or library for handling special characters in JSON

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you want to send a json object using the url itself (that is, as a parameter). If security doesn't matter you (it will be visible), you could just encode using `[Base64][1]`.

You should probably play with your `json` object to convert it to a `byte[]`, called `jsonbytes`, for instance, then use `Base64.encodeToString(jsonbytes, Base64.URL_SAFE)` and sending this as a parameter.

Your server then should convert this Base64 encoded string into a json object, which tends to be straightforward if you're using PHP:

```
$jsonString = base64_decode($_GET['json']);
$json = json_decode($jsonString, TRUE);
```

This will give you an associative array in PHP. If you just want the json string, skip the last step.

Comment: In JSON URL i am sending °,Empty space (" "), i am using replace method but is there any method or library for handling special characters in JSON

Comment: Did you try any of our answers? What do you mean by "*sending °,Empty space (" ")*"? I think we both gave you two tools that could manage special characters. @Alex's would convert them into their ASCII codes, and mine would get the whole Json and pack into a safe string, just to unpack it in the server.